# Renaming a remote branch that doesn't exist locally

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm relatively new to git. I'm using bitbucket as my remote repository. After an attempt at converting all my branches to tags, I'm in a bit of a messy situation. I'm at a state where on bitbucket I have tags that have the same name as branches. I want to remove the extraneous remote branches.

Locally, I have what I want:

```
> git branch
* master

> git tag
1.1.0
1.2.0
1.3.0
1.3.1
1.3.2
2.0.1
```

So far so good.

On bitbucket, however, I have:

branches:

```
1.1.0
1.2.0
1.3.0
1.3.1
1.3.2
2.0.1
master
```

tags:

```
1.1.0
1.2.0
1.3.0
1.3.1
1.3.2
2.0.1
```

I want to delete all remote branches except master. How do I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete a remote object you have to push nothing to it — for instance,

```
git push origin :master
```

will delete whatever is named "master" in the remote repository.

Now the truth is that "master" here is just a *shortcut* for the full real name of that reference which is "refs/heads/master". Tags are in the "refs/tags" namespace, so if you happen to have both a branch and a tag named "foo" in your remote repository, you can use the full name of an object you want to delete to remove any ambiguity.

The gory details are described in the [`gitrevisions(7)` manual page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).

So, to delete all the remote branches except master you have to do something like this:

```
git push origin :refs/heads/1.1.0 :refs/heads/1.2.0 ...
```

You could try to make this less tedium by employing a little shell hack:

```
$ ( while read b; do echo :refs/heads/$b; done | xargs git push origin )
1.1.0
1.2.0
1.3.0
1.3.1
1.3.2
2.0.1
^D
```

(^D here means pressing `ctrl-d` to signalize end of input to the subshell).

---

P.S.
By the way, I thought that since Git supports wildcard refspecs when fetching, like

```
git fetch origin '+refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*'
```

that would work for pushing, too. But seems like it doesn't — at least

```
git push origin ':refs/tags/*'
```

does not seem to work for me with Git 1.8.1.

Answer (score 2):

```
git branch -m old_branch new_branch         # Rename branch locally    
git push origin :old_branch                 # Delete the old branch    
git push --set-upstream origin new_branch   # Push the new branch, set local branch to track the new remote
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax to delete a remote branch/tag is:

```
git push REMOTE_NAME :BRANCH_NAME
```

I'm not really sure if tags or branches have preference if they have the same name.

So to be more specific, you can specify it is a branch using the `refs/heads` refspec specifier:

```
git push REMOTE_NAME :refs/heads/BRANCH_NAME
```

Assuming your remote is named `origin`, this command should delete all the branches you mentioned:

```
for branch_name in 1.1.0 1.2.0 1.3.0 1.3.1 1.3.2 2.0.1; do
    git push origin :refs/heads/$branch_name
done
```

Comment: Yeah, realized that and edited my answer just before you posted the comment.